# What are reasons that makes <C-j> map to ^M instead of ^@?

Tags: key-bindings

I was using vim-tmux-navigator and `<C-j>` had always worked.

One day, I found it doesn't work anymore.

When doing `<C-v><C-j>`, `<C-v><C-m>`, `<C-v><enter>` in command mode, they all give me `^M`.
However testing on my colleague's Mac, the `<C-j>` would return `^@` instead.

All I know is:

1. The plugin maps `<NL>` and `<CR>` instead of some specific keystrokes
2. `:verbose map` shows nothing suspicious.  No `<C-j>` mappings.  Only mapping `<NL>` and `<CR>` to `:TmuxNavigateDown`.

Any ideas? (I am using iTerm2)

Comment: `^@` is the NULL byte (0x00), which is a weird key code to send

Comment: Last time I have a weird bug is that all my backslashes needs to be double escaped, and the cause was cpoptions.  This time I should be using the default cpoptions.. along with Tmux Navigator not working, my :Tags is using path relative to home instead of the project path (so I can't navigate to a tag..) and every time I edit vimrc it says that I have a swap file... Lemme see if I can make a minimal reproducible case for the <C-j> thing

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I tried `vim -u NONE` and `:nn <NL> ij<esc>` and pressing `<C-j>` doesn't work, but `:nn <C-m> ij<esc>` would insert the `j` when I press `<C-j>`.  How may I carry on any investigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a very weird issue.  After "fixing", my `<C-j>` is now returning `^@` and the mapping to `<NL>` worked.

It should be a Tmux session problem.  After turning off tmux and re-attaching the session again, everything is fine.

P.S. for whoever also getting the other issues addressed in the comments, those are really separate issues -- the tags is that I moved `tags` from project root to `.git` thus the paths are all wrong; and the `vimrc` is because there is really a swap file there which is being edited in some halted vim process.